# Unique username/email from 2 CSVs, one existing, one to generate from

Tags: powershell

I need to compare all users in a CSV from Google with their names and email address, to a CSV from our internal system of users where I use a formula to generate username/emails for new people. I want to switch to a nightly export and script (on a Windows host, so PowerShell) versus a manual excel/google sheets process. Usernames must be unique. We do fist initial + last name (up to a hyphen), and the last 2 number of their assigned ID. We remove all spaces from that. We add one more number from there ID for duplicates.

Here are my 2 big issues, plus I am sure there is an easier script to do all this.

If John Smith(jsmith11) leaves, Jack Smith (jsmith111) and all other jsmiths try to grab jsmith11. They already have usernames in the file, and should just use that.

Also if the script is making a bunch of usernames, I am not checking against what is already created. Like jsmith1111, another jsmith1111. I think I have to keep a 3rd data set and compare to that as well.

```
$sis  = import-csv ".\sis_test.csv"
$google = import-csv ".\google_test.csv"
function MakeUsername{
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$user_fname,
        [Parameter()] 
        [string]$user_lname, 
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$user_ID, 
        [Parameter()]
        [int]$user_ID_len=2
    )
   $fname = $user_fname.substring(0, 1)
   $lname = $user_lname -replace '\s+', ''
   $lname = $lname.Split('-',2)[0]
   $len = $user_ID.ToString().length -$user_ID_len
   $idnum = $user_ID.ToString().substring($len)
   $username = $fname+$lname+$idnum+"@domain.com"
   $username = $username.ToLower()
    return $username
}
function CheckUsername{
    param(
        $CUusername,
        $CUcsv,
        $CUfirstname,
        $CUlastname,
        $CUid,
        [Parameter()]
        [int]$CUidcount = 2
    )
    $CUrow = $CUcsv | where {$_.primaryEmail -eq $CUusername}
    $CUgivenName = $CUrow."name.givenName"
    if($CUusername -eq $CUrow.primaryEmail -and $CUfirstname -eq $CUgivenName)
        {
        return $CUusername
        }else{
                if($CUgivenName -eq $null)
                {
                    return $CUusername
                }else{
                    $newuser = MakeUsername $CUfirstname $CUlastname $CUid $CUidcount
                    $CUrow = $CUcsv | where {$_.primaryEmail -eq $newuser}
                    if($newuser -eq $CUrow.primaryEmail) ##That user name exists
                    {
                        ### Repeat the process as we found the same ID, but add 1 more part of the ID
                        $CUidcount++
                        CheckUsername $newuser $CUCSV $CUfirstname $CUlastname $CUid $CUidcount
                    }else{
                        return $newuser
                    }
                }
            }
}

foreach($row in $sis){
    #cleanup FistName spaces
    $rowFistName = $row."First Name"-replace '\s+', ''
    $username = MakeUsername $rowFistName $row."Last Name" $row."OnCourse Id"
    $username = CheckUsername $username $google $rowFistName $row."Last Name" $row."OnCourse Id"
    [pscustomobject]@{
        OCName = $rowFistName+" "+$row."Last Name"
        Username = $username
     }
}
```

Here is my CSV data for sis_test.csv

```
First Name,Middle Name,Last Name,OnCourse Id
John,,Smith,12345611
Jack,,Smith,12345111
Joe,,Smith,12341111
Jane,,Smith,12345622
Jennifer,,Smith,12345222
Jordan,,Smith,12345612
Joana,,Smith,12345122
Joanne,,Smith,12342111
Jake,,Smith,12311111
Jill,,Smith,12345322
Jay,,Smith,12345412
Ja’ay,,Smith,12345672
Ja ray,,Smith,12345678
Jacob,,Smith,12411111
```

Here is my CSV for google_test.csv

```
primaryEmail,name.givenName,name.familyName
jsmith11@domain.com,John,Smith
jsmith111@domain.com,Jack,Smith
jsmith1111@domain.com,Joe,Smith
jsmith22@domain.com,Jane,Smith
jsmith222@domain.com,Jennifer,Smith
jsmith12@domain.com,Jordan,Smith
jsmith122@domain.com,Joana,Smith
```

I am sorry if this isn't formatted well, first time posting so much code here. So if you remove John Smith from google_test.csv it will try to assign jsmith11 to everyone ending in 11, like Jack and Joe, Joanne, Jake, Jacob. Also, as mentioned all the "new" users from sis_test.csv aren't compared to each other. Jake and Jacob Smith will be given then same jsmith11111.

Sadly this took me 2 days to get working in a broken manner...worked with my actual live data and a couple new adds...but broke when I used test data, which has a scenario I encountered in the past.

Thank you for any tips / help!

Answer (score 0):

Running your script, the output is:

[image]

Create an array to store all the existing usernames from `google_test.csv`. This will help you check against existing usernames more efficiently.

After modifying, now the `CheckUsername` function runs a loop that iterates until a unique username is found. Inside this loop, it checks if the generated username already exists in the array of existing data. But when it fails, the increment of the ID part and regenerate the username until it's unique.

By using a while loop, this function will keep generating new usernames until it finds one that doesn't already exist in `google_test.csv`.

This should help address the issue of multiple users trying to grab the same username and ensure that all new users from sis_test.csv are compared against each other to guarantee unique usernames.